# oracle: UTL_SMTP - crlf ignored in mail text when concatenating 2 or more variables

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using UTL_SMTP which works ok (mail is being delivered) but I'm struggling with crlf behavior in the final output.  For explaination, see pseudo code below with result behavior.  (actual code is within a cursor within a stored procedure)

--good example
    p_body := p_body||'Intro text line0: '||crlf||crlf;

```
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line1: '||nvl(curs_rec.cursor_value1,0)||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line2: '||curs_rec.cursor_value2||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line3: '||curs_rec.cursor_value3||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line4: '||curs_rec.cursor_value4||crlf;
```

desired results in;

Intro text line0:

Some text line1: value1

Some text line2: value2

Some text line3: value3

Some text line4: value4

-- odd behavior example  (only difference is 2 variables are being concatenated on line 2 instead of 1)

```
p_body := p_body||'Intro text line0: '||crlf||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line1: '||nvl(curs_rec.cursor_value1,0)||' additional text '||curs_rec.cursor_value5||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line2: '||curs_rec.cursor_value2||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line3: '||curs_rec.cursor_value3||crlf;
    p_body := p_body||'Some text line4: '||curs_rec.cursor_value4||crlf;
```

undesired results in;

Intro text line0:

Some text line1: value1 additional text value5 Some text line2: value2 Some text line3: value3 Some text line4: value4

The good news is value 5 is being included.  The bad news is all is written on one line instead of separate lines.  The only way I get crlf to work is to double up with ||crlf||crlf; but that results in a blank line in between outputs.  (which I prefer not to have occur)  I've tried passing Chr(13)||Chr(10) in various combinations.  I've used to_char to remove any implicate conversion issues, but to no avail.  Is concatenating 2 variables on one line causing subsequent crlf to be ignored?  (that's what it appears to be happening) And if so, how to avoid such behavior?

Comment: What MIME type is used?  Is the email being read as HTML instead of text?

Comment: Hi, I added tab - CHR(9) before the crlf and that solved the issue.  I.e, p_body := p_body||'Some text line1: '||nvl(curs_rec.cursor_value1,0)||' additional text '||curs_rec.cursor_value5||CHR(9)||crlf;